Horror movie about a family moving into a haunted house
I am looking for a horror movie that's already a couple of years old. The scene begins with a girl that is being attacked by rats and when the servant comes in it disappears. A new family moves in the home and there are crazy things happening. Like there is splashing blood out of a cup of milk in front of the door. And also the daughter is being kidnapped by a scary old woman through the window. The daughter is kept locked in the basement behind a wall and the father is breaking the wall, so he can rescue her. And also there is a statue of a sitting devil on top of the house.

House of the Damned [AKA Spectre] from 1996.

Will and Maura, despite their marital problems, decide to come to Ireland and live on Maura's ancestral estate, bringing with them their daughter Aubrey. But soon weird happenings around the house lead a local priest to confess that Maura's ancestors practiced black magic, and Maura's own insecurities threaten to bring her into the evil fold.

Everything you mentioned is in there. Here's the trailer, that includes the scene with the blood spurting from a bowl of milk around the half minute mark:



